# How do I access the property:value pairs in this JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following JSON file called `levels.json`. It is stored on the server.

```
{
    "level1":
    [{
        "shape1":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":25,
            "positiony":25,
            "color":"rgba(255,0,0,1)",
            "number":"3"
        },
        "shape2":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":100,
            "positiony":25,
            "color":"rgba(0,255,0,1)",
            "number":"3"
        },
        "shape3":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":25,
            "positiony":100,
            "color":"rgba(0,0,255,1)",
            "number":"3"
        },
        "shape4":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":100,
            "positiony":100,
            "color":"rgba(255,255,0,1)",
            "number":"3"
        }
    }],
    "level2":
    [{
        "shape1":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":25,
            "positiony":25,
            "color":"rgba(255,0,0,1)",
            "number":"3"
        },
        "shape2":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":100,
            "positiony":25,
            "color":"rgba(0,255,0,1)",
            "number":"3"
        },
        "shape3":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":25,
            "positiony":100,
            "color":"rgba(0,0,255,1)",
            "number":"3"
        },
        "shape4":
        {
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "positionx":100,
            "positiony":100,
            "color":"rgba(255,255,0,1)",
            "number":"3"
        }
    }]
}
```

The HTML file below (shapefromjson.html) is also stored on the server within the same directory as the JSON file above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Shape From JSON</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ajax_get_json()
{
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "levels.json", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            var results = document.getElementById("results");
            results.innerHTML = "";
            //var i = 1;
            for(var level in data)
            {
                //var j = 1;
                //results.innerHTML += "Shape: "+i+"<br />";
                for(var shape in level)
                {
                    //results.innerHTML += j+"<br />";
                    results.innerHTML += "w: "+data[level][shape].width+"<br />";
                    results.innerHTML += "h: "+data[level][shape].height+"<br />";
                    results.innerHTML += "x: "+data[level][shape].positionx+"<br />";
                    results.innerHTML += "y: "+data[level][shape].positiony+"<br />";
                    results.innerHTML += "n: "+data[level][shape].number+"<br />";
                    results.innerHTML += "c: "+data[level][shape].color+"<br /><hr />";
                    //j++;
                }
                //i++;
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
ajax_get_json();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get in the browser is: "[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data[level][shape].width') onreadystatechange (shapefromjson.html, line 31)"

Comment: Why are all your values arrays if they never contain more than one element?

Comment: `level*` is an array of objects, and you can't iterate over that with a for-in loop like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proper code (tested, working, improved readability):

```
for (var level_index in data){
    var level = data[level_index] ;
    for (var layer in level){
        var shapes = level[layer];
        for(var index in shapes){
            var shape = shapes[index];

            results.innerHTML += "w: "+= shape.width + "<br />"; //And so on.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I access the shape name (so to speak)?

Comment: `for(var index in shapes){` where `index` is the shape name. Test it by `alert(index);`

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var level in data)
     {
      for(var shape in data[level]) //Problem is here
                {
   //Your code
}
```

But I think you should use a for loop for your inner one because this is an array.

```
for(var level in data)
    {
    for(var i=0; i< data[level].length;i++ ) //Problem is here
       {
           for (var shape in data[level][i]){
              results.innerHTML += "w: "+data[level][i][shape].width+"<br />"; //use i as index

           //Your code
        }
```

Comment: Could you show me what format the output has to be in? e.g.: `data[level][0][shape].height+`

Comment: This produces "W: undefined"

Comment: @Mike: oh, you have 1 more inner loop to go. I'll update the answer

Comment: @Mike: check updated answer. In your case, you have only 1 item in the array, so `data[level][0][shape].height` could also work. But we should use an array loop in case we have more items, the code still works.

Answer (score 0):

Please first include jQuery library in your page like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then write html code and make a button and set onclick on that button like:

```
<input name="" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getJson();"/>
```

After this write java script code like:

```
var shape1Width;
var shape1Height;
var shape1Positionx;
var shape1Positiony;
var shape1Color;
var shape1Number;

function getJson() {
$.ajax({
   type: "Get",
        url: "http://www.json-generator.com/j/bORzQjYsZe?indent=4",
        async: false,
       success: function(data){
       var len1=data.level1.length;
       var len2=data.level2.length;
       for(var i=0;i<len1;i++){
          shape1Width=data.level1[i].shape1.width;
          shape1Height=data.level1[i].shape1.height;
          shape1Positionx=data.level1[i].shape1.positionx;
          shape1Positiony=data.level1[i].shape1.positiony;
          shape1Color=data.level1[i].shape1.color;
          shape1Number=data.level1[i].shape1.number;
       }
       alert("width:"+shape1Width+",height:"+shape1Height+",PositionX:"+shape1Positionx+",PositionY:"+shape1Positiony+",Color:"+shape1Color+",Number:"+shape1Number);
      },
   error: function(errorMsg){
    alert(errorMsg);
   }
});
}
```

Comment: Here I add code for accessing details of only one object please follow the same procedure for accessing all the abject.